# what type of variable is one that opens a file?

Tags: python, variables

I know that if a variable is a word then it is a string.
If it has numbers it is a float.

What type of variable would it be if it opens a code.
Here is my code:

```
problem = open('problems.txt')
lines=problem.readlines()
```

Comment: *"Open file and return a corresponding [__file object__](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)."* - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
type(problem)
```

Which gives you :

```
<type 'file'>
```